# Do I have to repeat possessive pronouns in a list?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, possessives, lists

Would it be okay to write:

Nevertheless, we will analyze it because of its straightforward computation, prevalence in research and lack of qualitatively different results with other measures.

or do I have to repeat the possessive pronoun?

Nevertheless, we will analyze it because of its straightforward computation, **its** prevalence in research and lack of qualitatively different results with other measures.

Comment: I find the latter easier to parse.

Comment: If you're going to repeat them, I would repeat them in all instances: *and* ***its*** *lack of . . .*

Answer (score 1):

You should either repeat the pronoun in all items of the list or only use it in the first item.

> Nevertheless, we will analyze it because of its straightforward computation, prevalence in research, and lack of qualitatively different results with other measures.

or

> Nevertheless, we will analyze it because of its straightforward computation, its prevalence in research, and its lack of qualitatively different results with other measures.

I also recommend using a [serial comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) particularly in rather wordy lists. (There are many conflicting opinions about this style choice.)